# Otro problema más con Index: 2, Size: 2 (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android-studio, android-sqlite

Veo que es un tema recurrente en los que están empezando a programar como yo. Pero de todos los foros que he leído no he podido sacar una conclusión para mi problema particular.

Me encuentro con el siguiente problema:
Estoy guardando en la base de datos 4 columnas: id, titulo, url y prioridad
Cuando se introducen los datos, todo funciona perfectamente, se guarda todo como debería. Pero a la hora de recoger esos datos y mostrarlos ocurre lo siguiente:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{es.ifp.playlistonline/es.ifp.playlistonline.ReproductorActivty}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
```

Y ya no sé que demonios hacer :(

Este es mi código completo de la activity:

```
    package es.ifp.playlistonline;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ReproductorActivty extends AppCompatActivity {

    // COMPONENTES DE LA PÁGINA
    protected VideoView video;
        //Base de datos
        protected BaseDatos db;

    // ADICIONALES
        // VerVideo
        private ArrayList<String> verVideo = new ArrayList<String>();
        private ArrayAdapter<String> adaptadorSpinner;

    // VARIABLES
    private String titulo = "";
    private String url = "";
    private int prioridad = -1;
    private Bundle extras;
        // Controlador de vídeo
        private MediaController mc;
        // Para pasar de pantalla
        private Intent pasarPantalla;
        private int id = 0;
        private String contenidoItem = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reproductor);

        db = new BaseDatos(this);

        video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView_reproductor);

        extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        titulo = extras.getString("id");

        //https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_5MB.mp4
        verVideo = db.getListaRepro(id);

       
        System.out.println(verVideo.get(0));
        System.out.println(verVideo.get(1));
        System.out.println(verVideo.get(2)); // AQUÍ ME MARCA EL ERROR, GET() Y GET(1) LO PILLA PERFECTAMENTE
        System.out.println(verVideo.get(3));

    }
}
```

Y esta la parte de la base de datos SQLite:

```
   public ArrayList<String> getListaRepro(int id) {
    Cursor res = null;
    String titulo = "";
    String url = "";
    ArrayList<String> verVideo = new ArrayList<String>();
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM PlayListOnline WHERE id = '"+id+"' ", null);
    res.moveToFirst();
    if( res != null && res.moveToFirst() ){
        titulo = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("titulo"));
        url = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("url"));
        res.close();
    }
    verVideo.add(titulo);
    verVideo.add(url);

    return verVideo;
}
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda :)

Comment: Al final del método `getListaRepro` estás agregando solamente dos elementos (titulo y url) a `verVideo` por eso te lanza la excepción `IndexOutOfBoundsException` cuando intentas imprimir el tercer elemento.

Comment: Siempre que veas el error `IndexOutOfBoundsException` considera que estás intentando acceder a un índice que no existe dentro de un array. Por tanto, como bien te señala @GlennSandoval, tu array tiene solamente dos elementos. Otra cosa que confunde a los programadores al inicio es que los índices de arrays empiezan con `0`, por lo que para leer el primer elemento debes usar `elArray(0)`  y para el segundo `elArray(1)`. Puede que esa sea parte de la confusión al creer que como tiene dos elementos el segundo lo obtendrías con `elArray(2)`, y no, pues el 2º elemento está en el índice 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta línea

```
private ArrayList<String> verVideo = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Puede ser resumida así:

```
private ArrayList<String> verVideo;
```

Luego:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reproductor);

    db = new BaseDatos(this);
    verVideo = db.getListaRepro(id);
    //resto código
```

Siguiendo, tienes un problema con tu método, a tu consulta le estas diciendo que te traiga todos los datos de todas las columnas de tu BD:

```
res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM PlayListOnline WHERE id = '"+id+"' ", null);
```

Pero, luego solo le pasas dos:

```
    titulo = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("titulo")); //posición 0 del array
    url = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("url")); //posición 1 del array

verVideo.add(titulo); //posicion 0
verVideo.add(url); //posicion 1
```

¿Cómo quieres mostrar los demás datos si no los estas pasando?

Otra cosa, como recomendación personal, no uses variables así:

```
'"+id+"'
```

Puedes hacer algo como:

```
public ArrayList<String> mostrarDatosDelPjFlor(String idVideo) {
    ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    this.abrirDBLeer();
    String titulo = "";
    String url = "";
    String[] id = {String.valueOf(idVideo)};
    String consulta = "SELECT * FROM PlayListOnline WHERE id = ?";
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(consulta, id);
    if(cursor.getCount() <= 0){
        cursor.close();
        Sistem.out.println('Nada para mostrar');
    }else{
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            titulo = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("titulo"));
            url = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("url"));
            lista.add(titulo);
            lista.add(url)
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    return lista;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seguro que el query que esta filtrando por id te devuelve 4 registros ?

Ya que el siguiente error

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2

significa que tu array solo tiene 2 elementos y estas intentando leer un tercero, por eso el get(0) y get(1) funcionan bien.

Te recomiendo ver tu BD, ya que puedes tener 4 registros en la BD, pero en el query:

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM PlayListOnline WHERE id = '"+id+"' ", null);
```

Estas filtrando por id